# jQuery File Upload upload_dir vs upload_url

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

When using jQuery file upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), in the UploadHandler.php there is the option for upload_dir and upload_url.

From a discussion here ([How do I change the default upload path for jquery file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478053/how-do-i-change-the-default-upload-path-for-jquery-file-upload)), they are using upload_dir to change the path. Then, what is the purpose of upload_url? What is the difference between this two?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- ***upload_dir*** --> upload directory :P
- ***upload_url*** --> temp link to download the recently uploaded file, you could use the same as the *upload_dir* (I did that).

I suggest to add the *upload_dir* and *upload_url* as parameter when initializing the class (just like the first answer from the discussion that you mentioned), otherwise you can experience some issues...

```
$my_upload_path = '/dir/to/my/upload/path/';
$options = array ('upload_dir' => $my_upload_path , 'upload_url' => $my_upload_path);
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

I hope it could be helpful.

Comment: $options = array(
            'upload_dir' => $dir,
            'upload_url' => $dir,
            'print_response' => false,
            'max_file_size' => 100000000,
        );

I'm still getting Undefined index: upload_url